# How do I install the latest version of nmap from source on Ubuntu?

Tags: make, configure, nmap

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, and I am trying to install the latest nmap.  I have a C compiler installed.

I ran `openssl version` and found that this version was installed:
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

I downloaded nmap 7.31 as a .bz2 file.  I decompressed it.  I ran the ./configure utility like this:

```
./configure --with-openssl=/usr/bin/openssl
```

I received this message:

```
... configure: error: Your version of OpenSSL does not support
SHA-256. Please install OpenSSL 0.9.8 or later. configure: error:
./configure failed for nping
```

I ran `whereis openssl` and the result of the command confirmed my location was correct.  If I run ./configure by itself, I get a warning about compiling nmap without openssl.

```
WARNING: You are compiling without OpenSSL
```

I try to use `make` afterward that and get

```
make The program 'make' can be found in the following packages:  *
make  * make-guile Try: apt install <selected package>
```

If I try apt install, I get the local network nmap installation.  I do not want that.  I tried gmake, but I got this `No command 'gmake' found.`

How do I install the latest nmap utility?  I cannot run ./configure with the explicit designation of the OpenSSL location.  I cannot run make after a normal "./configure" run.

Comment: You *probably* just need to install the `build-essential` and `libssl-dev` packages and then `./configure` *without* setting an explicit `--with-openssl` path (which is likely not a binary path anyhow)

Answer (score 4):

I am not that familiar with `nmap` but I built the very latest version from source reasonably easily under Xenial Xerus with a few easy steps.

**Step 1:**

First activate the Software Sources:

```
Dash > Software & Updates > Ubuntu Software > Downloadable from The Internet > Source Code
```

and allow the Repositories to reload.

**Step 2:**

Then install the build dependencies as well as `checkinstall`:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nmap
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

**Step 3:**

Then run the following single command to download, compile and install the latest `nmap`:

```
mkdir $HOME/Desktop/nmap_build && cd $HOME/Desktop/nmap_build && \
wget https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-7.31.tar.bz2 && tar xavf nmap-7.31.tar.bz2 && \
cd nmap-7.31 && \
./configure && make && \
sudo checkinstall --pakdir "$HOME/Desktop/nmap_build" \
     --backup=no --deldoc=yes --pkgname nmap --pkgversion 7.31 \
     --fstrans=no --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default
```

**Step 4:**

On my system this shows:

```
andrew@athens:~$ nmap --version

Nmap version 7.31 ( https://nmap.org )
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Compiled with: nmap-liblua-5.3.3 openssl-1.0.2g libpcre-8.38
               libpcap-1.7.4 nmap-libdnet-1.12 ipv6
Compiled without:
Available nsock engines: epoll poll select
andrew@athens:~$
```

Hopefully this will also work well on your system :).

Answer (score 1):

The `configure` script is asking for the location of the OpenSSL library headers and `*.so` files, not the `openssl` executable. On Ubuntu/Debian systems, you can install these headers by installing the `libssl-dev` package. If you install it this way, you do not have to provide the location to the configure script; it will find it on its own.

As another user pointed out, you can also run `apt-get build-dep nmap` to install all the prerequisites for building the `nmap` package, but this might be more than you want. Both will work.